# Registering input in TEdit (Delphi/Free pascal)

Tags: linux, delphi, freepascal

I have a TEdit field and I need to invoke an action from actionlist on pressing ENTER/RETURN button while focused on it(Like in most search engines). 
Using Lazarus 0.9.28.2-12 and Ubuntu 11.04

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Handle the OnKeyDown event and test for `Key=VK_RETURN`.

Comment: Yes, and then you might also wish to peek and remove the keyboard message(s) so that the beep goes away. Or, you can use `OnKeyPress` with `ord(Key) = VK_RETURN`.

Comment: Thanks guys, it worked. But before using VK_RETURN you should also include LCLType lib: `uses LCLtype;`

Answer (score 0):

Better use OnKeyUp instead of OnKeyDown. The reason for this is that if you press Enter it can generate many events (in fact it will generate until the key is pressed) which is not desirable. Using OnKeyUp and checking if Key is VK_RETURN will be much better and will fire only 1 event until the next release occurs.

Comment: the standard is for actions to be fired on key down not key up. Using key up is wrong.